# How to conditionally escape strings in JSON?

Tags: json-format

If you JSON export an association with a url, it will espace the forward slashes like this:

```
ExportString[ <|"url" -> "http://s2d3.scene1.com/medium/94760712386071_001.jpg"|>, 
"JSON"]
```

[image]

How can I get this *not to happen*?

Comment: So `// StringReplace["\\/" -> "/"]` is not an option?

Comment: In practice, it would be during a call to `Export` not `ExportString` and only a few of the fields are URLs (don't want to un-escape all of them).

Comment: @kuba Are you saying do this: `Export["~/Downloads/tmp.json", ExportString[<|"a" -> "http://a.b/c:de", "b" -> 123, "c" -> <|"url" -> "http://s2d3.scene1.com/medium/94760712386071_001.jpg"|>|>, "JSON"] // StringReplace["\\/" -> "/"], "Text"]`

Comment: I thought there was probably some Export suboption to do this

Comment: I think you need to export as `"String"` not `"Text"` to not double encode. It may not matter here but unless I am mistaken, it should be `"String"`.

Comment: @Kuba Right, still that global StringReplace is kind of dangerous no?

Comment: There's no way to do this from JSON Export directly (even in any undocumented way), some kind of StringReplace on ExportString and Exporting as "String" like @Kuba has recommended would be the best solution most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if there is a neat solution but here is one approach. Assuming you can mark your urls with `URL`:

```
json = <|"url" -> URL @ "http://s2d3.scene1.com/medium/94760712386071_001.jpg"
  , "urlω2" -> URL@"http://wolfram.com"
  |>;

FileTemplateApply[#, #2[[1]], "file.json"] & @@ 
Reap @ 
ExportString[
  json
, "RawJSON"
,  "ConversionFunction" -> Function[Sow[First@#]; "``"]
]
```

```
FilePrint@"file.json"
Import["file.json", "RawJSON"]
```

> {
>     "url":"http://s2d3.scene1.com/medium/94760712386071_001.jpg",
>     "urlÏ2":"http://wolfram.com" 
>   }
>
> ```
> <|"url" -> "http://s2d3.scene1.com/medium/94760712386071_001.jpg",  
>     "urlω2" -> "http://wolfram.com"|>
> ```