# How to export a list of url strings as a json file?

Tags: export, json-format

I want to export a list of `url`'s as a JSON file.

For instance:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.json", {"https://www.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/"}, "JSON"]
```

Unfortunately mathematica adds back slashes to the file.

```
[
"https:\/\/www.google.com\/",
"https:\/\/www.google.com\/"
]
```

## Question:

how to export a list of `url`'s to a JSON file?

Comment: It seems that escaping / characters is allowed in JSON but not mandatory. So the result is valid JSON and I think every JSON interpreter should read this back as the original strings (that is without the backslashes). You can for example check that Mathematicas `Export` does this. Can you explain why you don't want those slashes to be escaped?

Comment: @AlbertRetey your right! I didn't realise that escaping characters was allowed. Thanks

Comment: you are welcome, I have added another answer with some more details for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the [(more or less) official standard description](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) correctly, a `/` is allowed to be escaped with `\` as `Export` does, but does not have to be escaped. Thus the JSON that `Export` generates is valid and should be read back as the original string (without the escape character) by any correctly implemented JSON import code.

So if you are just longing for valid JSON, then there is nothing to do. If for any reason you want to get rid of the escape characters, that can be done like in your own answer and the result will still be valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

adapting @Kuba's [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/190885/36681) to a similar question.

```
jsonExport[file_, listOfURLs_]:=FileTemplateApply[#, #2[[1]], file] & @@ Reap@ExportString[URL /@ listOfURLs, "RawJSON", "ConversionFunction" -> Function[Sow[First@#]; "``"]]
```

.

```
jsonExport[NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.json", {"https://www.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/"}] // Import
```

> ```
> {"https://www.google.com/", "https://www.google.com/"}
> ```